# Performance issue in ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have created the table with 50 rows and gave the css overflow is scroll to parent element of table. Each time of scrolling I will add 5 row in the table. It’s working fine in html. But I converted this to ionic framework, I got performance lag. Can any one suggest, why performance issue is occurring when perform DOM operation in ionic framework?

Comment: Try to use only ionic components, because they are optimised to mobile environment. Rendering issues are common in mobile hybrid apps, it is not ionic fault but builded in apps browsers. Next is that angularJs is doing many DOM operations, so changing from tipical DOM modification to angular can do visible perfomance issues.

Answer (score 3):

Remember to use the **one-time-binding operator '::'** in every angular directive that should execute or evaluate only once, I mean if you don't need to be watching for changes (ng-click, ng-class, ng-if, ng-switch...) and also in labels, texts, fields and stuff filled with your data.

Doing a **ng-repeat** with too much angular interaction can create a lot of watchers. Hence, the perfomance of your app will decrease dramatically. Imagine an ng-repeat of a portion of html with 1 ng-click, 1 ng-class and three fields. These are 5 watchers, so **5 X 50 rows are 250 watchers**...

Also if your list is not going to change you can use algo **::** on the ng-repeat directive. Example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in ::ctrl.items"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-repeat="item in items"`, for ionic you can use `collection-repeat="item in items`. It is a really optimized version of ng-repeat for ionic. For more info checkout this link: [collection-repeat in ionic](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/)